# iTextSharp 7 cell in another cell with border

Tags: itext

If I have created a cell within another cell using iTextSharp 7, how could I set the inner cell's border?
All the styles apply to the inner cell, except border?

Comment: By default, the border of a cell is never rendered if the cell is used outside the context of a table (unless you write a custom `CellRenderer` in which you override the `drawBorder()` method). That means that the border of an inner cell will never be rendered if you nest cells. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve when you say that you create a cell within another cell. That doesn't make sense. There is probably a workaround for what you're doing, but as you don't explain why you want to create a cell without another cell, it's hard to guess which result you are expecting.

Comment: Does it apply to other properties as well?

Comment: No, it applies to borders, because iText 7 fixes a problem that existed in iText 5: two adjacent cell draw borders in iText 5, resulting in overlapping lines. In iText 7, it isn't the cell that draws the borders (unless you use a custom `CellRenderer`). Instead, the border are drawn at the table level. Only one line is drawn between two cells. Your question still isn't clear: what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Well, there are many.

Comment: The main issue is to make some custom layout. If I rely on a table with cells having col and row spans, and I need some cell to be expanded on 5 rows and to its left 5 cells, each one its row, it simply crashes with some null pointer exception or illegal index value...

Comment: On the other hand, if I create two cells on a row, one having a table in it, that table with cells, then I need to put border to some cells, which it does. Except that I don't want a border between the cells, just around them, it draws some border out of nowhere between, or I can't figure out the reason..

Comment: Bonus: I can't align the content of the cells, or their paragraphs inside the cells, one to the left, one to the right. All stay to the left all the time.

Comment: OK, I don't understand what you mean, but if you now combine your comments into a consistent question with some code samples, maybe someone will understand and be able to help you out.

Comment: I wrote a couple of dozen iText 7 examples involving tables and cell: http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/tree/develop/publications/highlevel/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/highlevel/chapter05 I didn't experience any of the problems you mention. Then again: you don't really ask a question. You just claim "I can't do this; I can't do that." Those aren't questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118452/discussion-between-mike-and-bruno-lowagie).

Comment: My time is too precious to chat.

Comment: @Mike please simply provide your pivotal code, the observed result and the expected result to have something concrete to discuss.

Comment: Actually I give up due to "My time is too precious to chat." comment.